# Generate redirects from a list in Jakarta Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect

I'm pretty experienced in HTML, CSS, javascript, SQL, IIS, and a little Apache, but have essentially no knowledge of Java or Tomcat. I have a client with a low budget and a legacy web site based on a proprietary CMS ([an ancient version of this](http://tmsasia.com/cms/index.jsp)) built on jakarta tomcat. Upgrading is not an option and paying tms to develop is also not an option. I'm much cheaper.

The URLs of the pages and documents on the site tend to be pretty long and not very meaningful to humans. For one reason or another when they are doing promotions they want shorter URLs for particular content. For example they may want `http://{server}/naftir.html` to redirect to  `http://{server}/cmspreview/content.jsp?id=com.tms.cms.section.Section_1013_sub_options`.

I've solved this by a kludge of putting (for example) a naftir.html file in the root directory of the server and writing the redirects in there. But the {whatever}.html files are piling up and it seems there should be a better solution. E.g. edit the 404 file to look in a list (or MySQL table) of short names and desired redirects to do the redirection if found, otherwise display the 404. Or some other method based on a list of short names and redirect URLs rather than loads of files.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does http://tinyurl.com/ serve your purpose better?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily configure a lot of this kind of stuff using a tool called [urlrewrite](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). It's a `Filter` that you configure in `WEB-INF/web.xml` to run for all the URLs you want to re-map. Then, there is a "rewrite" configuration file where you can map specific incoming URLs to outgoing URLs. You can even use parametric replacements like mapping `/foo/*` to `/a/b/c/d/*`.

You can simplify the configuration by mapping the `urlrewrite` filter to *all* URLs, but then you lose a bit of performance on all the URLs that aren't ultimately rewritten.